# How does this code snippet find a palindromic substring from a string?

Tags: ruby

In one of the [Ruby Game challenges](http://www.therubygame.com/challenges/4), you're asked to find the longest palindromic substring in a given string, so from `abacdfgdcabaypqqpy` you should extract `ypqqpy`. One of the given submissions [that doesn't use regex] was this:

```
w = string.size
l = (w.to_f / 2).ceil
l.upto(w-1) do |j|
  i = w-j
  l.upto(w-i+1) do |n|
    s = string[n,i]
    return s if s == s.reverse
  end
end
```

Would anyone care to give a quick rundown on how it works?

P.S Is this a valid SO question?

Comment: Problem is, this code is *not correct*. It fails for input like `"addaabcd"`, where the palindrome is in the first half. No point in explaining it, but if you want I can hack together some code that works without regexes, together with an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said, this is not a valid solution, it will for example fail for the input `"addaabcd"` (or any other string where the palindrome is in the first half of the word). An obvious (although not very efficient) solution could be:

```
# iterate over possible palindrom lengths
# (in descending order)
string.size.downto(0) do |n|
  # iterate over possible palindrome locations
  0.upto(string.size - n) do |i|
    # extract the substring
    s = string[i,n]

    # is the substring a palindrome?
    # If yes, we found our solution, because we know 
    # that no longer palindrome exists
    return s if s == s.reverse
  end
end
```

Comment: The regex fails to find palindromes that starts with letters contained in shorter palindromes earlier in the string. Example: `"ppop" => "pp"`.

Comment: @Lars: Nice catch! The point was that it's possible to match palindromes with a regex in many languages, although the language of palindromes is not regular. But this seems to be a bad example :)

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution

```
str = "addaabcdaddadcba"
length = str.size

all = [] # contains all possible palindromes of the string

0.upto(length - 2) do |start|
  (start+1).upto(length - 1) do |finish|
    check_str = str[start,finish] # check each possible substring 
    next if finish - start == 1 # ignore single letter strings
    all.push(check_str) if check_str == check_str.reverse # if the string and its reverse are equal then it is a palindrome
  end
end

p all.max_by(&:size)
```

Comment: In addition, this code has an error: it should be str[start..finish], not str[start,finish] as the latter uses "finish" number of chars from start.